# React Router Link not changing URL or component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a spotify track search app with two main components, `Home` and `TrackList`. I'm using React-Redux to manage the state. `Tracklist` gets rendered when the search field in `Home` gets submitted and is successful. I have a home button that's wrapped in a `Link` tag inside the `TrackList` component so that I can go back to the 'home page'.

The problem I'm having is that when I click the button, the URL does not change and the home component does not render. All it does is trigger an apparent refresh of the `TrackList` component as the spotify iframes reload. However, if I refresh the page at the following url: `localhost:3000/results`, there are no tracks listed (as expected) but the button now works! It takes me back to the home component and the URL changes back to `localhost:3000`.

I've tried the `withRouter()` option as well as manually pushing to history, both of which have not worked.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './Home';
import TrackList from './TrackList';
import NotFound from './NotFound';

const App = ({ store }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
          <Route path='/results' component={TrackList} />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import SearchField from './SearchField';
import ErrorContainer from './ErrorContainer';
import '../styles/Home.css';

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className='ui container' id='home-container'>
      <ErrorContainer />
      <Header />
      <SearchField />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**TrackList.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import '../styles/TrackList.css';

const TrackList = props => {
  const data = props.tracks;
  const list = data.map(item => {
    return (
      <div
        key={item.track.id}
        className='ui one column centered grid track-item'>
        <div className='row'>
          <h3>{data.indexOf(item) + 1}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <p>Artist: {item.track.artists[0].name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <p>Track: {item.track.name}</p>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <iframe
            title={item.track.name}
            src={`https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=${
              item.track.uri
            }&theme=white&view=coverart`}
            width='300'
            height='80'
            frameBorder='0'
            allowtransparency='true'
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });
  return props.error ? (
    <Redirect to='/' />
  ) : (
    <div className='ui container track-list-container'>
      <Link to='/'>
        <button>Home</button>
      </Link>
      <h1 className='centered-header'>{`${
        props.country
      } Top 10 on Spotify`}</h1>
      {list}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    tracks: state.tracks,
    error: state.error,
    country: state.countrySearched
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(TrackList);
```

I want to be able to go back to the home component via the home button. Please help!

Comment: Your code looks good to me, could you provide a codepen or similar? https://codesandbox.io/s/7m90pkm5k0?from-embed

Comment: Remove that Redirect component from your component and check.

Comment: @josemigallas There are too many files for me to include as I'm also relying on some actions and reducers which receive information from an express backend server that calls the spotify API when one of the home sub-components mounts.

Comment: @DehandeCroos Tried that but no luck. As I mentioned above, the home button **does** work but only when I refresh the url path that the TrackList component is matched to and it does not contain any data.

Comment: I recommend you make it simpler and try again, in order to isolate the error. I copied your classes (without redux) in a codesandbox and it works fine.

Comment: It works if I change my TrackList component to just return some static code. The issue seems to be when my TrackList component receives props from the Redux store and uses them to dynamically render content (as I want it to). If I refresh the page which removes all the dynamic content that's generated, the button works. I just can't figure out how that's stopping the URL from updating and from rendering the correct component...

Answer (score 0):

instead of the link component, can you try this?

```
<button onClick={() => props.history.push('/')}>Home</button>
```

Comment: Tried it. Still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Turns out I had some code in the `SearchField` sub-component inside the `Home` component that was redirecting the app back to `/results`. Once I removed that it worked like a charm! The only change I had to make was to wrap `connect()` and `SearchField` with `withRouter()` and use `this.props.history.push('/results')` when submitting the search to get to the `TrackList` component to render.